# Cannot Run Ionic Serve

Tags: cordova, ubuntu, ionic3

I have two ionic-v3 apps. One of them is working perfectly. but when i run `ionic serve` on other apps, I get an error

> npm run ionic:watch:before
>
> app-generator@0.0.1 ionic:watch:before /home/sts/Workspace/Projects/SOBAT/mobileapp
>   node copy-skeleton.js && node copy-assets.js

```
Copy Done!

TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cliutils/lib/gulp.js:73:62
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:110:62)
at <anonymous>
```

Here my ionic info

> cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

> global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1) 
Gulp CLI              : CLI version: 2.2.0 Local version: 4.0.2
```

> local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
Cordova Platforms  : android 8.1.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

> System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.12.0
npm               : 6.4.1 
OS                : Linux 4.15
```

> Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : /home/sts/Workspace/System/android-sdk
```

> Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Can someone please tell me what this error is?

Thanks

Comment: Try `ionic repair`

Comment: i got this error
    ```[ERROR] Unable to find command: repair```

Comment: Solved With Update Ionic CLI to 5.2.7